# Obtain value from DataGrid to a Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Can some 1 help me with how to use button column in **datagird**? my requirement is when u click respective button in the column ..data belongs to that respective button column should be filled with **textboxes** in below

asap

thnks :)

this is the class i used to load data to the datagird

```
public void getGrid_viewproblem (GridView a)
{
    con = new SqlConnection();
    cstring();
    data = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Complaint", con);
    build = new SqlCommandBuilder(data);

    ds = new DataSet();
    data.Fill(ds, "A");

    a.DataSource = ds.Tables["A"];
    a.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: sacitha you should do more home work !

Comment: pls elaborate more... looks like u posted the question in haste.. :)... Like what do u want to do with the grid. U mean add a dynamic button column, or get the value of the row after adding a dynamic button column or get the entire grid during post back... explain in detail

Comment: i added the button control to the gird.my requirmrent is when i click 
on button in datagird resepective coloum data should be filled with textboxes
 in the next webpage.. in order to do that i need to obtain the primary key
 of that column .so basically what i want is when 
i click on button primay key of that coloum need to be assigned to a session

Comment: how are you adding columns in gridview. Autogeneration=true of false

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AutoGenerateColumns="False" in grid view then Add the Columns

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("ID") %>' CausesValidation="false" CommandName="EditData" Width="55px" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And then add the OnRowCommand Event.

In OnRowCommand Event check the Condtion

```
e.CommandName == "EditData"
```

if the condition satisfies then get the data(PRIMARY KEY) by e.CommandArgument and do as you want